# Javascript - delete object from reference

Tags: javascript, object

I have one tree-like structure containing block with certain id. Then I have another object, that contains 'id' : objectPart pairs.

Tree:

```
var tree = [
    {
        'property' : 'value',
        'id' : 'someID',
        //more properties...,
        'content' : [
            {
                'prop' : 'something',
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'prop' : 'val',
        ...
        'content' : []
    }
]
```

ID index:

```
{
    'someID' : tree[0]
}
```

I need some way how when I do `delete ID_index.someID`, that object gets also deleted from main structure.

Structure after this code should look like this:

```
[
    {
        'prop' : 'val',
        ...
        'content' : []
    }
]
```

Comment: The only way to do that is to also delete the property in the other object. If you do this a lot you can create a utility function that does both.

Comment: If you create a `new` instance you won't have to worry about deleting the original.

Comment: @PHPglue, new instance of what? there are no constructors here

Comment: You can make an `new` instance of any Object. Please see answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `delete` you can write your own remove function. It should look like this:

```
function myRemove(stringId) {
    delete ID_index[stringId]; //remove property from ID_index
    objIndex = ... //find object index in tree array
    tree.splice(objIndex, 1); //remove object from tree array
}
```